# java multidimensional array notation

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

To create an length 5 int array, we use the syntax:

```
 int[] x = new int[5]
```

To create a 2 dimensional array, an array of int arrays, we say:

```
 int[][] x = new int[5][];
```

This creates an array of length 5, which can hold int[] objects.

For this second case, why isn't the syntax this: ?

```
int[][] x = new int[][5]
```

After all, 5 defines how many int arrays we can have. Not the size of the int arrays that we're going to put into x.

Comment: You've answered your own question -- you have an array of length 5 (the first dimension) which holds arrays of potentially any length (the second dimension).

Comment: for the second dimension you would have to allocate what size you want that array to be: `x[0] = new int[5]; // etc...`

Comment: Okay, so putting ``[]`` after something indicates an array, right? so ``foo[]`` is an array of ``foo``. ``foo[] = new foo**[5]**`` is a length 5 array of foo.

By the same token, ``int[][]`` is an array of ``int[]``, so I would think that ``int[][] = new int[]**[5]**`` would be a 5 length array of ``int[]``. What Louis said makes sense about aesthetic appeal, but I'm just asking if the rule is "being broken" in this case... or am I understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be really weird to have the indices for *lookups* be different from the indices for *construction*.  So if you had `int[][] x= new int[][5]`, then you'd look up the elements with `x[0..4][foo]`, which is just more confusing than the alternative.

Comment: Okay, so putting ``[]`` after something indicates an array, right? so ``foo[]`` is an array of ``foo``. ``foo[] = new foo**[5]**`` is a length 5 array of foo.

By the same token, ``int[][]`` is an array of ``int[]``, so I would think that ``int[][] = new int[]**[5]**`` would be a 5 length array of ``int[]``. What you said makes sense about aesthetic appeal, but I'm just asking if the rule is "being broken" in this case... or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: No, it's a deliberate violation of the rules to minimize the total awkwardness.

Answer (score 0):

The array bring declared is the first dimension, so declaring the referenced array size does nothing to allocate the actual array.  It would be similar to coding this:

```
int[] a = new int[];
```